# Как при наведении на кнопку Tkinter изменить положение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button, hover

Есть код:

```
from tkinter import *
import random as rnd
def on_enter(e):
    myButton['bg'] = 'green'                       #####################
    myButton.place['relx'] = rnd.uniform(0, 1)     # <- вот тут ошибка #
                                                   #####################
def on_leave(e):
    myButton['background'] = 'SystemButtonFace'

root=Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry('200x200')
myButton=Button(root,text='ОТПРАВИТЬ')
myButton.place(relx=.1,rely=.1)


myButton.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
#myButton.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

root.mainloop()
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на кнопку положение элемента менялось. Я пробовал так: 
`myButton.place['relx'] = rnd.uniform(0, 1)` , 
но выходит ошибка: 
`TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment`. Подскажите как быть. Другие варианты решения проблемы принимаются.

Comment: insolor, можно поподробнее, а то не въехал...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для изменения параметров размещения виджета размещенного с помощью `place` нужно использовать метод `place_configure`:

```
def on_enter(e):
    myButton['bg'] = 'green'
    myButton.place_configure(relx=rnd.uniform(0, 1))
```